# how to fetch the only column data from excel which is there in database table column in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, excel

I have an excel file of 150 columns with specific column headings. In my database,have a table  '**ExcelImport** ' with column **ExcelHead** (contains data of column headings which have same name as excel column heading).

```
create table ExcelImport( id int primary key,ExcelHead varchar(max))

insert into ExcelImport values(1,'Role'),(2,'Manager')
```

this table will get data based on another rule. What my requirement is that i need to fetch the only column data from excel which is there in ExcelImport table and insert into another temp table. From the example i need to fetch only 'Role' and 'Manager' excel column and need to insert into temp table.

**Note**: Every time ExcelImport table data will truncated and new values for ExcelHead will be inserted.

Can any one suggest the coding for doing the same??

Comment: ,let me confirm this with you. You have a database name **ExcelImport** which has a column **ExcelHead** . **ExcelHead** will contain the column name of excel file you wanted to insert into another table.  What you wanted to do is that you wanted your program to open an excel file and get only the data which has the same column that you had previously added into *ExcelHead* column and add that data into another table.

Comment: ExcelImport  is the table name..

Comment: What you said is correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            DataSet ExcelDataset = DBcom.GetDataset();
            //add logic for getting excel imported data in dataset format.
            string[] columnsNames = new string[100]; int loop = 0;

            //Comparing the Imported Excel Column With Database Table Column
            foreach (DataColumn column in ExcelDataset.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                string clnameExcel = column.ColumnName;                
                int Exist = 0;
                foreach (DataTable table in DataBaseDataset.Tables)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                    {
                        string ColnamesDB = dr["DBColumn"].ToString();//DBColumn is the name of database table column name


                        if (CompclnameExcel == CompColnamesDB)
                        {
                            Exist = 1;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (Exist == 0)
                {                    
                    columnsNames[loop] = clnameExcel;
                    loop++;
                }
            }
            //Deleting Imported Excel Columns which is not there in Database
            foreach (string cNames in columnsNames)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cNames))
                {
                    ExcelDataset.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(cNames);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to read your column header from your excel file. Try looking [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1611627.aspx?Read%20Excel%20XLS%20XLSX%20files%20in%20C%20VB%20NET) to understand how to read column header from the excel file. Column header are usually first row of the excel file so it will be fine if you just read the first row of the excel file for column header. I will usually used a `Dictionary` to keep track of column header and it column index. Then you will need to use a sql to query `ExcelImport` table to get all the column name that you wanted to used as filter. And I will cross reference the two data (ExcelImport and Dictionary) to get all the row index of the excel file that needed to get.Then I will iterate all the row to get all the data of the excel file.Finally I will delete all the data from the `ExcelImport` and insert new data into `ExcelImport` table. You can look at pseudo code below.

```
    public Dictionary<string,int> GetDictionary(string fullExcelPath)
    {
           //Dictionary<Column Header,Column Index>

           Dictionary<string,int> columns=new  Dictionary<string,int>();

             ExcelWorkbook excelWorkbook = ExcelWorkbook.ReadXLSX(fullExcelPath);

             ExcelWorksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkbook.Worksheets[0];

             DataTable dataTable = excelWorkSheet.WriteToDataTable();

             DataTable columns=dataTable.Rows[0];

             //iterate to get the column header

             for(int i=0;;i++)
             {
                string header=(string )row[i];

                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(header))
                {
                       columns.Add(header,i);
                }
                else
                {
                   break;
                }
             }
           return columns;

    }

  public void DoWork()
  {
      Dictionary<string,int> columnsFromExcel=GetDictionary(excelPath);

      List<string> columnToFilter=GetFromDatabase();

      int[] columnIndex=CrossReferenceData(columnsFromExcel,columnToFilter);

      //column index=index we wanted to get data from
      //GetDataFromExcel =basically same as GetDictionary but it read from //second row instead of first row and used columnIndex to get data from //dataTable (look GetDictionary method).
      List<string> dataFromExcel=GetDataFromExcel(columnIndex);

      DeleteExcelImportTable();

      // dynamically created your insert sql

      string insertSQL=GetInsertSQL(dataFromExcel);

      InsertExcelImportTable(insertSQL);

  }
```

Comment: Don't forget to run the code above from another thread instead of UI thread.

Comment: DataTable columns=dataTable.Rows[0]; is incorrect, dataTable.Rows[0] provides DataRow, you might be looking out for 
DataColumnCollection dc = dataTable.Columns

Comment: As @Mirnal Kamboj has pointed out DataColumnCollection dc = dataTable.Columns maybe better solution

Comment: @Lopht Ghost what is the name space for ExcelWorkbook

Comment: @Lopht Ghost your idea in correct but not working the same code in visualstudio2008.Can u help me

Comment: @Athul , what problem are you having in visual studio 2008?